# Is there a way to use dash in a tkinter app

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, plotly-dash, python-multithreading

Cannot use tkinter App at the same time and after dash has been closed

I am working with tkinter and dash. Upon clicking on a button in the tkinter app, a dashboard is opened on a browser. The issue is, while the browser is opened, and even if it is closed, I cannot use the tkinter app afterwards.

Extract from lauchDash.py

```
def openDashboard():
    app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SIMPLEX])
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app1.run_server(port=8050)
```

Extract from tkinter app

```
from threading import *
import dash

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

def button_click(self):
        # Lauch Dashboard 
        t1 = Thread(target = lauchDash.openDashboard())
        t1.start()
```

I have tried using multithreading, but I guess I have been using it wrong. Is there a way to use tkinter app along with dash?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code adding a little bit of my own to make it work.
So from what I gather the problem was when you called the `button_click` method the `tk` window would freeze.
The problem was simply that when you specified the threads target (i.e `t1 = Thread(target = lauchDash())`) you are passing the return value of the `lauchDash` method rather then its referance. So effectively you were executing the method directly when defining your thread rather then letting the thread call it. All you need to do to fix this is to remove the parentheses so as to not pass the method value but it's reference.

Here is an example of how you should do this.

```
from threading import *
import dash
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

def button_click():
    # Lauch Dashboard
    t1 = Thread(target = lauchDash)
    t1.start()

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.draw_widgets()

    def draw_widgets(self):
        start_dash = Button(self, text="Start", command=button_click)
        start_dash.pack()

def lauchDash():
    app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SIMPLEX])
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app1.run_server(port=8050)

# extract from tkinter app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps ! Edit your question or comment on my answer if you want more clarification.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your response. I'll definitely try this! 
Actually, I removed the tkinter components from a class I defined and instantiated it in a main. And it appears to be working... well at least for now